# Proving $A_5$ is the smallest perfect group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I am trying to find a streamlined proof that $A_5$ is the smallest perfect group, with respect to order ( a group is perfect if it has no abelian quotients except $\{e\}$). I know it follows directly from the classification of simple groups, as it is the smallest non-abelian simple group. Is there a way to obtain this result without too much work without using this tool?

Thanks in advance, this question is just for fun though, I really want to see what techinques we can come up with.

Comment: Proving something is the *smallest* for some property involves looking at all smaller things and verify that they do not have that property. I feel this is unavoidable. One can use Burnside's theorem   on solvability of groups of order $p^aq^b$ and eliminate all groups except those of order 30.

Comment: Oh nice, hadn't thought of that. And of course, for order $30$ it is easy since groups of order $2n$ (with $n$ odd) have a subgroup of index $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A perfect group that is not simple has a nontrivial perfect quotient.  As a result, finding the smallest nontrivial perfect group is *equivalent* to finding the smallest non-abelian simple group.

As P Vanchinathan mentions, we can use Burnside to eliminate all cases except order $30$.  A group of order $30$ with no abelian factor is isomorphic to a dihedral group, but every dihedral group has a subgroup of index 2.  But Burnside is a quite powerful result, with no elementary proof that I know of.

The usual elementary arguments proceed by case analysis, using the Sylow theorems.  [Here](https://concretenonsense.wordpress.com/2009/12/21/groups-of-size-less-than-60/) is an outline of a typical argument, for example.  Some cases are easy, while others require some work.  For example, I don't know of an easier way than the Sylow theorems and counting arguments to show that no non-abelian group of order $56$ is simple.

Comment: Nice, in fact groups of order $2n$ with $n$ odd have a subgroup of index $2$.

Comment: @dREaM Yes, and there is a more general fact that $G$ always has a subgroup whose index is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$.

Comment: that sounds false.

Comment: Do you mean if $|G|=pk$ with $p$ being the smallest prime dividing $|G|$ and $k$ coprime to $p$?

Comment: @dREaM Sorry, yes, you're correct.  I was confusing two different facts: if $p$ is the smallest prime divisor of $G$, then 1) any subgroup of index $p$ is normal, and 2) if a Sylow $p$-subgroup is cyclic, it has a normal complement.  These two imply that if $p$ only divides $|G|$ once, then $G$ has a normal subgroup of index $p$.

Comment: Oh, ok, I didn't know that! Very interesting. (part 1 I did know, but part $2$ no)